# How to prove $g(\frac{1}{2})=\pm\frac{4}{3}$ are not possible?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$ be a holomorphic function with $f(0) =0$ and $f'(0) =0$ then possible values of $f(\frac{1}{2}) $ are :

1. $\frac{1}{4}$
2. $-\frac{1}{4}$
3. $\frac{1}{3}$
4. $-\frac{1}{3}$

---

Given $f(0) =0$ and $f'(0) =0$ implies $0$ is zero of $f$ of multiplicity at least $2$.

Let $f(z) =z^2 g(z) $ for some holomorphic function $g$ on $\mathbb{D}$

Then $f(\frac{1}{2}) =\frac{1}{4} g(\frac{1}{2}) $

For $g(z) =1 $ and $g(z) =-1$ option $1) $ and $2) $ are possible.

But how to show that $g(\frac{1}{2})=\pm\frac{4}{3}$ are not possible ?

Initially I thought if such values of $g$ are possible then for some $z\in\mathbb{D}$ we may have $|f(z) |\ge 1$ .

Comment: @Arthur Finally I have done it. By maximum principal $|g(z) |\le 1$

Comment: $|g(z) |=|\frac{f(z) }{z^2}|<\frac{1}{r^2}$ for $0<r<1$ , then by maximum principal it follows that $|g(z) |\le 1$